# Windows Form Taking A Long Time To Close

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010

I have a simple Windows Form app that uses an `OpenFileDialog` and a `SaveFileDialog`. The form has a Close button that, when clicked calls the following code:

```
private void closeButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Dispose();
}
```

If I open the form and then click close in debug from Visual Studio 2010, the form closes and I am returned to Edit mode almost immediately. However, if I have opened either the OpenFileDialog or SaveFileDialog objects, and and either select a file or hit Cancel, and then hit Close, the form disappears instantly, but it can take up to 10 seconds for VS to return to Edit mode.

My code for these methods is pretty simple:

```
private void saveDirectoryButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();

    try
    {
        String path = Path.GetDirectoryName(settings.SavePath);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(saveTextBox.Text))
            path = Path.GetDirectoryName(saveTextBox.Text);
        sfd.InitialDirectory = path;
        String name = Path.GetFileName(settings.SavePath);
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(saveTextBox.Text))
            path = Path.GetFileName(saveTextBox.Text);
        sfd.FileName = name;
    }
    catch { /* Don't do anything */ }

    sfd.Filter = "Data File|*.dat|All Files|*.*";
    DialogResult result = sfd.ShowDialog();
    if (result == DialogResult.OK)
        saveTextBox.Text = sfd.FileName;
}
```

After hitting Close, the Output Window displays the following three lines:

```
The thread 'vshost.RunParkingWindow' (0x1b8c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The thread '<No Name>' (0x39c) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[6052] LogScanner.vshost.exe: Managed (v2.0.50727)' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The first two show up immediately, and the third one pops up just before Visual Studio goes back to Edit mode.

Does anyone have an idea as to why it is taking so long to return to Edit mode if I open one of these dialogs?

Comment: Possibly unrelated: don't call `this.Dispose()` - try `this.Close()` instead.

Comment: Also try wrapping `SaveFileDialog sfd = new SaveFileDialog();` in a `using` statement.

Comment: @Blorgbeard: I originally tried this.Close(), but had the same results. Good suggestion for the using--I'm not sure why I didn't do that, as I normally would have--but unfortunately, it didn't solve the issue.

Comment: I can't replicate this with Visual Studio 2013, a new forms project, a button that does `new SaveFileDialog().ShowDialog();` and a button that does `Dispose();`. Can you try it in a new clean project? Maybe it's actually something else in your code interacting with the dialog somehow.

Comment: Calling `Dispose` on the `Close` is a bad idea.  You should wrap the `Form` in a `using` when it's created instead.

Comment: What does your output window show while the limbo stage takes place?

Comment: @o_weisman: I have added to the bottom of my question the results from the Output window.

Comment: This is an environmental problem, pretty common on programmers' machine.  The shell dialogs load a ton of unmanaged DLLs into your process.  Shell extensions that you have installed on your machine.  You can see them getting un/loaded when you enable unmanaged debugging.  If the unload delay doesn't give you a hint then SysInternals' AutoRuns utility is a good way to find the troublemaker.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to close a single windows form you can use:

```
this.Close();
```

If you want to close the whole program you can use:

```
Environment.Exit(0);
```

The 0 is only the exit code, it's not important.
I hope it helps!